# Script Jquery it does't work

Tags: jquery

i have this part of script that 's not working  :

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $('.idbody').corner("bevelfold  cc:#026072 15px");

        });

    </script>
```

i created it  3days ago and it worked , now i don't understand ..

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: i don't have error it just does't work  ..there is no  corner in the div : idbody

Comment: Well, something changed, but the code you've provided isn't enough for us to help troubleshoot the problem.

Comment: for "corners" i need just this code and <div ID ="idbody" runat="server" >........ html code </div>

Answer (score 1):

jsFiddle shows it should work:
http://jsfiddle.net/Saran/S48c7/1/

These (reflecting your code) I used for test purposes:

Markup:

```
<div class="idbody"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.idbody {
  width: 100px;
  height: 66px;
  background-color: #fce;
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.idbody').corner("bevelfold  cc:#026072 15px");
});
```

Did you change the path to your local "Scripts/jquery.corner.js"?

Answer (score 0):

it  works... i just  added :

```
 <script src="Scripts/_jquery-2.0.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```